# Proxy a site with NGINX to another site

Tags: nginx, proxy, reverse-proxy

I have a site with some urls at ( http://location:port/ ) and want to use NGINX to proxy it.

I have another site, at (http://location2:port2) and want to proxy it as well such that.

1. Site 1 is accessed via `http://main.com` and
2. Site 2 is accessed via `http://main.com/site2` with all its sublinks

My attempt is failing.

```
server {
    listen  80;

    index index.html;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

        proxy_pass http://landing-page:5000;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }

    location /insights {
        return 302 $uri/;
    }

    location /insights/ {
        # proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        # proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        # proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        # proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

        rewrite ^/insights/?(.*) /$1 break;

        proxy_pass http://ghost:2368/;
        # proxy_redirect off;
    }
}
```

#### Additional Info

I'm running NGINX on Docker and must map port 80 to 8080 on my Mac.

I found is this:

1. `http://localhost:8080/insights` sets URL to `http://localhost/insights/` in the browser
2. `http://localhost:8080/insights/ghost` sets URL to `http://localhost:8080/ghost/`
3. `http://localhost:8080/insights/` sets URL to `http://localhost:8080/insights/`
4. `http://localhost:8080/insights/ghost/` sets URL to `http://localhost:8080/insights/ghost/`

ANY url with the ending slash seems to work well. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `location /` block should be at the end of the file. Location blocks are processed in order, and the first matching block will be executed. Since `location /` matches every request, it will always be executed.

In general, you should have your most specific blocks first, followed by your less specific blocks, finally ending with `location /` for all other requests.

Your file should be laid out thus:

```
server {
    listen  80;

    index index.html;

    location /insights/ {
        # proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        # proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        # proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        # proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

        rewrite ^/insights/?(.*) /$1 break;

        proxy_pass http://ghost:2368/;
        # proxy_redirect off;
    }

    location /insights {
        return 302 $uri/;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

        proxy_pass http://landing-page:5000;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }
}
```